# iOS app upload data to server as soon as network is available

Tags: ios, background, reachability

I have an app that tracks wildlife where the user enters data based on their observations (eg. user enters they see 3 moose). The data is then uploaded to a server. However, because this app will be used out in the field where there is often no internet connection, I want to save data if there is no connection, and upload the data as soon as the network is available

I know about Reachability, but it looks like I can only check if the internet connection is available at that moment, and doesn't check in the background for internet connectivity

So to summarize:

1. If there is an internet connection when users submits data, then that's fine.
2. If there is no internet connection, when user submits data, **I want to save this data. As soon as there is an internet connection, I want the data to be uploaded, without needing the user to open up the app again**.  I can't rely on the user to open the app again causing the data to be submitted, because they will likely only use this app out of the range of cell towers, and will likely NEVER run the app in a location with a network connection, so it would have to automatically submit this data for them.

Looking around, I can't find an answer so I'm beginning to wonder...is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Apple don't allow applications to run indefinitely in the background for this purpose, and they don't allow applications to be triggered remotely or anything of that nature.  At best you could have your application run in the background to get notifications about major location changes, but you'd have to have it as a proper feature rather than a hack to get around this limitation, otherwise your application won't get approved by Apple.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's possible to utilize the network in the background but only for a limited time after the user closes the app. You could create a timer which checks for a network connection (using Reachability or by pinging Google) and set the timer to fire every minute after the app closes. It's not a very efficient solution but it may work. You should look into how long you can maintain a connection after the app close though, I think it is 5-10 minutes.

Comment: Darnit...thought not. Thanks.